# Obj-C object is null

Tags: objective-c, forward-declaration

In my iOS app, I have forward declaration of "Person" class  in my AddPersonViewController class as follows.

```
@protocol PersonAddDelegate;
@class Person;
@interface AddPersonViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <PersonAddDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Person * person;

@end

@protocol PersonAddDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)AddPersonViewController:(AddPersonViewController *)addPersonViewController didAddPerson:(Person *)person;

@end
```

But when I try to call person object from the code as follows, I noticed that person is nil even though self.nameTextField.text returns string as expected:

```
self.person.personname = self.nameTextField.text;
```

I guess that it is about initializing 'person' but I am not sure of it. Any ideas about the problem and solution? Thank you in advance

Comment: What does this have to to with forward declaration? It seams that the problem is that you meber created a `Person` object and assigned it to the `person` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @property get you a backing iVar `_person`, and the person getter method and setPerson setter method, but you do not get a Person object.   It is nil by default and design.  If you want it to be non-nil, you should initialize it in the class's init method.

```
@implementation AddPersonViewController
-(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
        _person = [[Person alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Remember that in Objective-C you can send messages to uninitiated objects and you won't get an error message. A good practice that I use to troubleshoot these situations is to ``if (object) NSLog(@"something");``

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your answers. however even though I added the proposed initialization, I still have same problem. Morover, when I out breakpoint in if statement you proposed, I noticed that it is not hit.

Comment: Your view controller subclass is never used, then.  Often this has to do with the "Custom Class" of the VC object in InterfaceBuilder within XCode not matching your VC class.  If you are trying to load the VC programmatically instead, then you would need to post code about that problem.